# Multiple ArrayLists in ListAdapter [Android]

Tags: android, listview

**UPDATED CODE** after Niv's answer:

Here's my **Adapter** method:

```
public class PostsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

/**
 * ViewHolder class for layout.<br />
 * <br />
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    public final RelativeLayout rootView;
    public final TextView postUname;
    public final TextView postText;
    public final ImageView postPlatform;
    public final ImageView postImage;
    public final VideoView postVideo;

    private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, TextView postUname, TextView postText, ImageView postPlatform, ImageView postImage, VideoView postVideo) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.postUname = postUname;
        this.postText = postText;
        this.postPlatform = postPlatform;
        this.postImage = postImage;
        this.postVideo = postVideo;
    }

    public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
        TextView postUname = (TextView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.post_uname );
        TextView postText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.post_text );
        ImageView postPlatform = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.post_platform );
        ImageView postImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.post_image );
        VideoView postVideo = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.post_video );
        return new ViewHolder( rootView, postUname, postText, postPlatform, postImage, postVideo );
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if ( convertView == null ) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.post_list, parent, false );
        vh = ViewHolder.create( (RelativeLayout)view );
        view.setTag( vh );
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Object item = getItem( position );

    Log.d("Text", item.toString());
    vh.postText.setText(item.toString());

    return vh.rootView;
}

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

// Constructors
public PostsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
}
```

}

Now, the question is, how do I pass multiple arraylists, like I have eight arrays from which I have to populate the list.
Like, for every item, I have to get eight items to show for that item, I have those eight arraylists sorted to keep a one-to-one correspondence.

Any idea how to handle multiple arraylists?

Comment: RecyclerView is the way

Comment: What if I want to save images once they're showed in the view too?

Comment: Use view holder pattern for your adapter

Comment: Please check this link for [ListView](http://androhub.com/android-listview/)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code. A sample Adapter

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public final FrameLayout rootView;
    public final ImageView imHotelProfile;


    private ViewHolder(FrameLayout rootView, ImageView imHotelProfile) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.imHotelProfile = imHotelProfile;

    }

    public static ViewHolder create(FrameLayout rootView) {
        ImageView imHotelProfile = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.im_hotel_profile );
        ImageView imLike = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.im_like );

        return new ViewHolder( rootView, imHotelProfile);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if ( convertView == null ) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.list_adapter, parent, false );
        vh = ViewHolder.create((FrameLayout) view);
        view.setTag( vh );
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    GsonObj item = getItem( position );

    // TODOBind your data to the views here
    // fill data

    return vh.rootView;
}

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

// Constructors
public ListAdapter(Context context, List<GsonObj> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public ListAdapter(Context context, GsonObj[] objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

}

Comment: I have a RelativeLayout. Does it matter? How much? @Niv

Comment: No change it to RelativeLayout.

Comment: But I already have a RelativeLayout.
Should I change it to FrameLayout or RelativeLayout?

Comment: you can use relative layout itself

Comment: Change the last 2 constructors(ListAdapter) according to your number of arrays

Comment: How to do the super call then? :/

Comment: You will get everything you need as they will generate your adapter class by pasteing your xml    https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/

Comment: Got it, and it is working correctly, thanks.
But I have 8 ArrayList<String>, I put them in a List<ArrayList<String>> but how do I inflate the inflater such that in every listitem, I want to show the element at a specific position in every array list.
Like at position 0, I want a String from ArrayList1 and from ArrayList2 and .... ArrayList8.
Can we take this discussion to chat?

Comment: Thank you @Niv. How do I handle multiple arraylists

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand fully your question, but you can pass List parameters like this

```
List<List<String>> datalist = new Arraylist<>();
```

or

List of object list that contains String list

Hope, this will help you